# Cecilia5 software loading problem

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, python

`I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and trying to install Cecilia5 software from here:
http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/cecilia5doc/
and from apt. I checked all the dependencies, seem all to be met. The problem is: either starting from the installed apt version or following the Cecilia install documentation on the website, I get the same error-message.
Found out that (sorry quite newbeeish) it's the graphic interface, tried to change the arguments at the Widgets.py doc: changes but no success. If anyone could help, it'd be fantastic, thank you!

This is the error-message when starting cecilia from terminal:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cecilia/Resources/Widgets.py", line 2065, in createKnobBitmap
rec = wx.Rect(0, h2, w, self.sliderHeight)
TypeError: Rect(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:

  overload 1: too many arguments

  overload 2: argument 4 has unexpected type 'float'

  overload 3: argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'

  overload 4: argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'

  overload 5: argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'

  overload 6: argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
```

What is going on before the above mentioned error-message in the terminal is here (the above posted error message at the end):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/wx/core.py", line 2346, in Notify
    self.notify()
  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/wx/core.py", line 3552, in Notify
    self.result = self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cecilia/Resources/splash.py", line 102, in OnClose
    self.callback()
  
File "/usr/bin/cecilia", line 59, in onStart
    ceciliaMainFrame.onOpen(CeciliaLib.getVar("lastCeciliaFile"),
  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cecilia/Resources/CeciliaMainFrame.py", line 227, in onOpen
    CeciliaLib.openCeciliaFile(self, event, builtin)
  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cecilia/Resources/CeciliaLib.py", line 755, in openCeciliaFile
    if not getVar("audioServer").openCecFile(cecFilePath):
  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cecilia/Resources/audio.py", line 1788, in openCecFile
    CeciliaLib.getVar("mainFrame").onUpdateInterface(None)
  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cecilia/Resources/CeciliaMainFrame.py", line 305, in onUpdateInterface
    ceciliaInterface = CeciliaInterface.CeciliaInterface(None, title='Interface - %s' % title, mainFrame=self)
  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cecilia/Resources/CeciliaInterface.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.grapher = getGrapher(self)
  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cecilia/Resources/Grapher.py", line 1646, in getGrapher
    return CECGrapher(parent)
  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cecilia/Resources/Grapher.py", line 1330, in __init__
    self.toolbar = ToolBar(self, tools=['save', 'load', 'reset', 'show'],
  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cecilia/Resources/Grapher.py", line 1172, in __init__
    self.convertSlider = ConvertSlider(self, self.GetParent())
  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cecilia/Resources/Grapher.py", line 1577, in __init__
    PlainSlider.__init__(self, parent, 50, 2500, 200, log=True, outFunction=self.onSlider1)
  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cecilia/Resources/Widgets.py", line 2037, in __init__
    self.createKnobBitmap()
  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cecilia/Resources/Widgets.py", line 2065, in createKnobBitmap
    rec = wx.Rect(0, h2, w, self.sliderHeight)
TypeError: Rect(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: too many arguments
  overload 2: argument 4 has unexpected type 'float'
  overload 3: argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
  overload 4: argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
  overload 5: argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
  overload 6: argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
```

Comment: One thing that looks odd here is that it's finding wx components in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ rather than in the more standard /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ - did you install wxWidgets from source instead of (or as well as) from the Ubuntu repository?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and toughts. I'm sure I followed the docuemntaion on the ceclilia website
http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/cecilia5doc/src/intro/requirements.html for installing additional components with apt and pip. Unfortunately I don't know why wx components are installed there where you mentioned them. Maybe I did both installing proceses with apt, pip and from source. Thanks again for any hints how to proceed!

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  It looks like you meant this as a reply to [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1445533/cecilia5-software-loading-problem#comment2522777_1445533).  However, since you created a second account, you aren't able to comment, since *this* account isn't the owner of the question.  Please log in under the account you posted the original question, and then you'll be able to reply in a comment.  Thanks!